# Regex parsing issue

Tags: regex, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON output with regex, from this page: http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/api/nature%20rune

The strings I'm trying to extract are `"price":"x"`, with x being any number.

The query I'm attempting is: `(?<=\"price\":\")[0-9]+`, however this isn't working.

Could anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java, but I don't think that matters, does it?

Comment: _Why_ would you want to use RegEx for this? Just _parse_ the JSON, and then access the parts of the resulting data structure that you need.

Comment: FWIW, the language you're working with does matter because certain languages implement regular expressions differently.

Comment: @user3613821 - It can matter in some cases. Some programming languages don't implement all of the expected regular expression syntax, or implement it slightly differently. Tools such as `grep` can also implement an entirely different subset of regular expression syntax :)

Comment: @user3613821 - Also, it seems to [work okay for me](http://rubular.com/r/5wlfQWr9ZV). What is the exact code you're using?

Comment: `"` isn't a reserved character, the `\"` to escape them is unnecessary.